# asynchronous slower than synchronous

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My program does the following:

- take folder of txt files
- for each file:

  - read the file
  - do POST request to an API in localhost using file content
  - parse XML response (not in the example below)

I was concerned with performance of synchronous version of the program so tried to use `aiohttp` to make it asynchronous (it's my first attempt of async programming in Python besides Scrapy). It turned out that the async code took 2 times longer and I don't understand why.

SYNCHRONOUS CODE (152 seconds)

```
url = "http://localhost:6090/api/analyzexml"
package = #name of the package I send in each requests
with open("template.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    template = f.read()

articles_path = #location of my text files

def fetch(session, url, article_text):
    data = {"package": package, "data": template.format(article_text)}
    response = session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(response.text)

files = glob(os.path.join(articles_path, "*.txt"))

with requests.Session() as s:
    for file in files:
        with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                article_text = f.read()
        fetch(s, url, article_text)
```

Profiling results:

```
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ncalls | tottime | percall  | cumtime | percall  |               filename:lineno(function)               |
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|    849 |   145.6 |   0.1715 |   145.6 |   0.1715 | ~:0(<method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects>) |
|      2 |   1.001 |   0.5007 |   1.001 |   0.5007 | ~:0(<method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects>)   |
|    365 |   0.772 | 0.002115 |   1.001 | 0.002742 | ~:0(<built-in method builtins.print>)                 |
+--------+---------+----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

(WANNABE) ASYNCHRONOUS CODE (327 seconds)

```
async def fetch(session, url, article_text):
    data = {"package": package, "data": template.format(article_text)}
    async with session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data)) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def process_files(articles_path):
    tasks = []

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        files = glob(os.path.join(articles_path, "*.txt"))
        for file in files:
            with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                article_text = f.read()
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session=session, 
                                        url=url, 
                                        article_text=article_text
                                        ))
            tasks.append(task)
            responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            print(responses)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(process_files(articles_path))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Profiling results:

```
 +--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+
    | ncalls | tottime | percall | cumtime | percall |           filename:lineno(function)           |
    +--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+
    |   2278 |     156 | 0.06849 |     156 | 0.06849 | ~:0(<built-in method select.select>)          |
    |    365 |   128.3 |  0.3516 |   168.9 |  0.4626 | ~:0(<built-in method builtins.print>)         |
    |    730 |   40.54 | 0.05553 |   40.54 | 0.05553 | ~:0(<built-in method _codecs.charmap_encode>) |
    +--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I am clearly missing something in this concept. Could someone also help me understand why print in async version takes so much time (see profiling).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's not asynchronous :)

Look at your code: you do `responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` *for every file*, so you basically run fetching in sync, every time paying all the price of coroutine handling.

I suppose it's just an indentation error; if you unindent `responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` so that it's past the `for file in files` loop, you will really start `tasks` in parallel.

Comment: Is it faster now?

Comment: yes! went down to 70 seconds which is more acceptable. Thanks!