# Synchronous reading faster than asynchronous reading using thread pools on moderate-sized JSON files

Tags: python, json, multithreading

The answers to [asynchronous slower than synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003803/asynchronous-slower-than-synchronous) did not cover the scenario I was working on, hence this question.

I'm using Python 3.6.0 on Windows 10 to read 11 identical JSON files named `k80.json` to `k90.json`, 18.1 MB each.

First, I tried synchronous, sequential reading of all 11 files. It took **5.07**s to complete.

```py
from json import load
from os.path import join
from time import time


def read_config(fname):
    json_fp = open(fname)
    json_data = load(json_fp)
    json_fp.close()

    return len(json_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUM_THREADS = 12
    idx = 0
    in_files = [join('C:\\', 'Users', 'userA', 'Documents', f'k{idx}.json') for idx in range(80, 91)]

    print('Starting sequential run.')
    start_time1 = time()

    for fname in in_files:
        print(f'Reading file: {fname}')
        print(f'The JSON file size is {read_config(fname)}')

    read_duration1 = round(time() - start_time1, 2)

    print('Ending sequential run.')
    print(f'Synchoronous reading took {read_duration1}s')
    print('\n' * 3)
```

**Result**

```
Starting sequential run.
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k80.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k81.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k82.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k83.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k84.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k85.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k86.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k87.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k88.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k89.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k90.json
The JSON file size is 5
Ending sequential run.
Synchoronous reading took 5.07s
```

Next, I tried running this using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the `map` function call, using 12 threads. That took **5.69**s.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from json import load
from os.path import join
from time import time


def read_config(fname):
    json_fp = open(fname)
    json_data = load(json_fp)
    json_fp.close()

    return len(json_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUM_THREADS = 12
    idx = 0
    in_files = [join('C:\\', 'Users', 'userA', 'Documents', f'k{idx}.json') for idx in range(80, 91)]

    th_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS)
    print(f'Starting mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run with {NUM_THREADS} threads.')
    start_time2 = time()

    with th_pool:
        map_iter = th_pool.map(read_config, in_files, timeout=10)

    read_duration2 = round(time() - start_time2, 2)

    print('The JSON file size is ')
    map_results = list(map_iter)
    for map_res in map_results:
        print(f'The JSON file size is {map_res}')

    print('Ending mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run.')
    print(f'Mapped asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took {read_duration2}s')
    print('\n' * 3)
```

**Result**

```
Starting mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run with 12 threads.
The JSON file size is
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
Ending mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run.
Mapped asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took 5.69s
```

Finally, I tried running this using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the `submit` function call, using 12 threads. That took **5.73**s.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from json import load
from os.path import join
from time import time


def read_config(fname):
    json_fp = open(fname)
    json_data = load(json_fp)
    json_fp.close()

    return len(json_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUM_THREADS = 12
    idx = 0
    in_files = [join('C:\\', 'Users', 'userA', 'Documents', f'k{idx}.json') for idx in range(80, 91)]

    th_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_THREADS)
    results = []
    print(f'Starting submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run with {NUM_THREADS} threads.')
    start_time3 = time()

    with th_pool:
        for fname in in_files:
            results.append(th_pool.submit(read_config, fname))

    read_duration3 = round(time() - start_time3, 2)

    for result in results:
        print(f'The JSON file size is {result.result(timeout=10)}')

    print('Ending submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run.')
    print(f'Submitted asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took {read_duration3}s')
```

**Result**

```
Starting submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run with 12 threads.
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
Ending submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run.
Submitted asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took 5.73s
```

**Questions**

1. Why does synchronous reading perform faster than threading when reading reasonably large JSON files like these? I was expecting threading to be faster given the file size and number of files being read.
2. Are JSON files of much larger sizes than these required for threading to perform better than synchronous reading? If not, what are the other factors to consider?

I thank you in advance for your time and help.

**Post-Script**

Thanks to the answers below, I changed the `read_config` method slightly to introduce a 3s sleep delay (simulating an IO-wait operation), and now the threaded versions really shine (**38.81s** vs **9.36s** and **9.39s**).

```py
def read_config(fname):
    json_fp = open(fname)
    json_data = load(json_fp)
    json_fp.close()

    sleep(3) # Simulate an activity that waits on I/O.

    return len(json_data)
```

*Results*

```
Starting sequential run.
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k80.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k81.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k82.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k83.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k84.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k85.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k86.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k87.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k88.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k89.json
The JSON file size is 5
Reading file: C:\Users\userA\Documents\k90.json
The JSON file size is 5
Ending sequential run.
Synchoronous reading took 38.81s




Starting mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run with 12 threads.
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
Ending mapped pre-emptive threaded pool run.
Mapped asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took 9.36s




Starting submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run with 12 threads.
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
The JSON file size is 5
Ending submitted pre-emptive threaded pool run.
Submitted asynchoronous pre-emptive threaded pool reading took 9.39s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In this case your task is processor bound and not I/O bound - your CPU can loop through the data at a fixed rate. If you chop up the task across multiple threads, it's still going to take the same amount of time because you're processor will only incrementally work on each chunk one at a time (across different threads). The only time you get a speedup is when the task at hand is IO bound - say if you were trying to get data from a website which is taking a long time (even a 50 micro second lag would be considered a long time compared to the rate at which your CPU could processes the data if it already had it).

   See my SO answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552764/3491991) for a bit more explanation.

   In an ideal world, in your case, multithreading would have taken the same amount of time as just performing the computation serially. However, in practice, it takes resources and *time* to actually break apart each task, allocate it to a thread, wait for each result, then finally stitch each result back together to return the final output to you. All of that adds up to the about 0.6 seconds longer run time you see in your parallelized output.
2. Larger JSON files would not speedup multi-threading. For that to happen, your JSON files in question would have had to be, say, hosted on a website. Lets break down what would happen in both the serial and parallel case:

   **Serial Case**

   Since the data transmission speed of the website is slow relative to the data crunching speed of your CPU, your CPU would sit idle waiting until the data was available. It would look like this:

   - CPU makes request to website for `JSON_file1.json`
   - Website sends `JSON_file1.json`
   - CPU processes / completes processing `JSON_file1.json`
   - CPU makes request to website for `JSON_file2.json`...
   - and repeat until each file is processed

   **Parrallel Case**

   Since the data transmission speed of the website is slow relative to the data crunching speed of your CPU, your CPU would sit idle waiting until the data was available. So if you distribute each task across threads you can initiate each JSON_file request almost at the same time (across multiple threads).

   - Threads 1 - 4 make request to website for `JSON_file1.json`, `JSON_file2.json`, `JSON_file3.json`, `JSON_file4.json`
   - Website begins to send each of the four requested `JSON_file`s
   - As each `JSON_file` is received, the CPU processes each file.
   - Once a task is completed, the thread is closed and any computation returned
   - If there are still more files to process, then another thread is spun up to repeat the above until all files have been processed.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed commentary, @zelusp. I have marked your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but in general for threading to be useful for speed your program needs to be waiting for IO. Threading does not give you access to parallel CPU threads, it just allows operations to run in parallel sharing the same CPU time and Python interpreter (if you want access to more CPU you should look at ProcessPoolExecutor)

For example if you were reading from multiple remote databases rather than local files there would be a lot of time your program was waiting for IO with no local resource use. In this case threading could help as you could do your waiting in parallel, or process one item whilst waiting for another. However as all your data is coming from local files you are probably already maxing your local disk IO, you can't read multiple files at the same time (or at least not any faster than you can read them sequentially). Your machine still has to complete all the same tasks with the same resources, it doesn't really have any 'downtime' in either variant which is why they take pretty much the same time.

Comment: Hello @SimonN, I'm accepting the other answer provided below by as it is much more detailed, but your answer helped provide clarity on why my scenario was not an IO-bound scenario as I assumed it was. I have upvoted your answer.